FirebaseStorage rules simply won't work inspite of there being no typo
{
"path": "/b/projectname.appspot.com/o/ibpxtIOZF8a21M51NvTgO4F3CyT2/backup.txt"
"method": "get"
"auth": {
"uid": "ibpxtIOZF8a21M51NvTgO4F3CyT2"
"token": {
"sub": "ibpxtIOZF8a21M51NvTgO4F3CyT2"
"firebase": {
"sign_in_provider": "google.com"
}
"email": "<email>.com"
"email_verified": true
"phone_number": ""
"name": ""
}
}
"time": "2024-06-25T16:10:40.940Z"
"params": {}
}

The above is the request
service firebase.storage {
  match /{bucketName}/{allPaths=**} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == bucketName;
  }
}


These are the Firebase rules
On the Flutter app, when I try to upload files, it simply will not work with the above Firebase rules.
However, if I change the line to allow read, write: if true , everything works exactly as expected.
I went to Firebase website to try the simulated reads. And as you can see, the UID is equal to bucket name, yet the reads are denied.
When i do simulated reads with the original Firebase rules, simulated access is denied and the condition request.auth.uid == bucketName is false. Even though they are equivalent as you can see on top.
